# Inside jquery function append html code got an error

Tags: jquery, html

This is My jquery function  here  i append html code inside the function. That's got an error

```
function onDivisionChange() {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : '/Example/selectDivision.html',
    data : ({
        id : $('#division').val()
    }),
    success : function(responseData) {

        if (responseData != null) {

            $('#student').find('td').remove().end().append('').val('-1');
            $.each(responseData, function(index, item) {

                $('#student').append(   
                    $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(item['id']),

                    $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                         '<a href="edit.html?id=' + item['id'] + '" >Edit</a>'),
                                                       ^ 
                                                       |_ Here Error Occured

  Error is the  '+ item['id'] + ' this line takes as string, not the id value 

   in browser Link as  ->   edit.html?id=' + item['id'] + '

            Correct format is  edit.html?id= 41            


                    $('<br />').val(item['id']).html(item['']));

            });
        } 
    }

});
```

}

If you know about this error please share your answer

EDIT

The page

```
function onStudentDivisionChange() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : '/Example/selectDivision.html',
        data : ({
            id : $('#division').val()
        }),
        success : function(responseData) {

            if (responseData != null) {

                $('#student').find('td').remove().end().append(
                        '').val('-1');
                $.each(responseData, function(index, item) {

                    $('#student').append(
                            $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                                    item['id']),
                            $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                                    item['name']),
                            $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                                    item['fatherName']),
                            $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                                    item['motherName']),
                            $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                                    item['admissionNo']),
                            $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                                    item['phoneNo']),
                            $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                                    '<a href="edit.html?id=' + (item['id']) + '" >Edit</a>'));
                    alert("Id:"+item['id']);

                });
            } else {
                $('#student').find('td').remove().end().append(
                        '<td th:text="${student}"></td>').val('-1');
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Please specify which error. Also please insert `console.log(JSON.stringify(item))` just before the error line, and report what it outputs.

Comment: @Amadan the error is type mismatch error because the ' + item['id'] + ' is take as string not the inside value i think it's because the wrong format of quarts

the Error show in console is
Field error in object 'student' on field 'id': rejected value ['   item['id']   ']; codes [typeMismatch.student.id,typeMismatch.id,typeMismatch.long,typeMismatch]

Comment: What is `item` - an array I guess - of what?

Comment: @user2310289: If it was an array, `item['id']` would be undefined. It *should* be an object.

Comment: Please provide that code

Comment: That error message "Field error...." seems to be an error generated by Spring framework, and nothing to do with clientside - neither jQuery nor HTML.

Comment: @Amadan why would an error generated by Spring framework but showing in the browser's console?

Comment: I have no idea, but googling a bit seems to indicate what I said. It certainly is no JavaScript error.

Comment: @Amadan iF I CHANGE THE code into <a href="edit.html?id= 41 " >Edit</a>') this will work correctly.. i don't know more about this i am just a beginer

Comment: @PrasanthAR: No, it won't, since you completely mangled the quotes. What you wrote can't possibly work. Please use copy and paste to show the exact errors and code.

Comment: @Amadan the code is $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html('<a href="edit.html?id=' +item['id'] + '" >Edit</a>')

Comment: @Amadan the error show in browser is

Comment: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult:1 errors
Field error in object 'student' on field'id':rejected value['  item['id']'];codes [typeMismatch.student.id,typeMismatch.id,typeMismatch.long,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes[student.id,id];arguments[];default message[id]];default message[Failed to convert property value of type'java.lang.String' to required type'long' for property'id';nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string:"'item['id']'"]

Comment: Yeah - somehow, your link gets generated incorrectly. However, I can't see any way for the code above to mess this up.

Comment: The error that you have posted is a server-side error not a browser error.

Are you saying that this error happens when you click on the `edit.html` link?

Comment: @user2310289 Yes when click the edit link the error shows

Comment: @Amadan i edit my question and the shows the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you update to your question.

try doing

```
success : function(responseData) {

$.each(responseData, function(index, item) {
   var id = this.id;
   alert(id);
```

or

```
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

see [jquery each loop examples](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquery-each-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try using `parseInt()` to convert it.

```
 $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                     '<a href="edit.html?id=' + parseInt(item['id']) + '" >Edit</a>')
```